# Left of . must have class/struct/union c++ error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open an input and output file by passing to a function by pointer reference but every time I try to compile the program an error appears: "left of '.open' must have a class/struct/union Can someone help look at what's wrong with this code?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void PrepareFiles(ifstream* fin, ofstream* fout);

int main(){
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    PrepareFiles(&fin, &fout);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void PrepareFiles(ifstream* fin, ofstream* fout)
{
    char inputFilename[MAX_LENGTH_FN + 1],
         outputFilename[MAX_LENGTH_FN + 1];

    cout << "Input filename (up to " << MAX_LENGTH_FN << " characters): ";
    cin.get(inputFilename, MAX_LENGTH_FN + 1, '\n');
    cin.ignore(999, '\n');
    cout << "Output filename (up to " << MAX_LENGTH_FN << " characters): ";
    cin.get(outputFilename, MAX_LENGTH_FN + 1, '\n');
    cin.ignore(999, '\n');

    *fin.open(inputFilename, ios::in);
    if (*fin.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening input file " << inputFilename;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *fout.open(outputFilename, ios::out);
    if (*fout.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening output file " << outputFilename;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either do `(*fin).`, or, even more idomatic, `fin->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` has higher precedence than `*`, so `*fin.open(inputFilename, ios::in);` (and others) are interpreted as `*(fin.open(inputFilename, ios::in));`, which is incorrect since `fin` is a pointer.

Use brackets or better yet, `->`. Or even better, pass the parameters by reference, I don't see a need to pass by pointer.

Comment: Oh okay thank you! I see what you're saying. I gotta pay attention to everything single statement because they all mean something different. Like on this one I needed a bracket because I was only using fin as a pointer, not the whole statement.